# Add Custom Generated ID with our own specification to Firestore with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

Currently i only know how to set an ID which takes one of the entity in the table.

```
//Create Mentee
app.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log(req.body);
      const id = req.body.NAME;
      const menteeJson = {
        NAME: req.body.NAME,
        LOCATION: req.body.LOCATION,
        SUBDISTRICT: req.body.SUBDISTRICT,
        LATITUDE: req.body.LATITUDE,
        LONGITUDE: req.body.LONGITUDE
      };
      const menteeDb = db.collection('mentee'); 
      const response = await menteeDb.doc(id).set(menteeJson);
      res.send(response);
```

as you can see here, this doc ID will be set the same with the NAME entity in the table.

## **My Goal**

I want it to be customized generated like for example: 'B67294','B91652','B93158'. It would be 6 digits and starts with the letter B followed with 5 digits number that increments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want firebase to generate id, you can omit the id when you call the doc method

```
 const response = await menteeDb.doc(~id~).set(menteeJson); // remove id
```

If you want to generate ids yourself, you can look for solutions like cuid2 or nanoid.